# doOnEach rather that flatMap/concatMap

Tags: java, couchbase, reactor, mutiny

## Introduction

I am currently working on a project to achieve a bulk insertion in a Couchbase database.
For this, I chose Quarkus Reactive to get data from the client. And I used a Flux to insert all the data to database.
For each data inserted, I send a response, example of a response:

```json
[
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "1"
            "created": "2022-02-22T00:28:34Z",
            "lastName": "DUPOND",
            "firstName": "Marianne",
            "gender": "FEMALE",
            "title": "MRS",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "street1": "rue du Testeur",
                    "zipCode": "34000",
                    "city": "MONTPELLIER",
                    "country": "France",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "number": "0610529856",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "emails": [
                {
                    "email": "marianne.dupond@test.com",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "birthday": "1987-11-13",
            "languages": [
                "FR",
                "EN"
            ],
            "socialNetworks": [
                {
                    "socialNetworkId": "marianne.dupond@twitter",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "customFields": [
                {
                    "customFieldKey": "MAIDEN_NAME",
                    "value": "DURAND"
                }
            ]
        },
        "result": "201",
        "id":"1"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id" : "2"
            "created": "2022-02-22T00:28:34Z",
            "lastName": "BOND",
            "firstName": "James",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "title": "MR",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "street1": "boulevard des services secrets",
                    "zipCode": "10000",
                    "city": "LONDRES",
                    "country": "Royaume-Uni",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "number": "0600700700",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "emails": [
                {
                    "email": "james.bond@test.com",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "birthday": "1950-07-07",
            "languages": [
                "EN"
            ],
            "socialNetworks": [
                {
                    "socialNetworkId": "james.bond@facebook",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "customFields": [
                {
                    "customFieldKey": "VIP",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "result": "201",
        "id": "2"
    }
]
```

## Problematic

But currently the returned response is:

```json
[
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "1"
            "created": "2022-02-22T00:37:39Z",
            "lastName": "DUPOND",
            "firstName": "Marianne",
            "gender": "FEMALE",
            "title": "MRS",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "street1": "rue du Testeur",
                    "zipCode": "34000",
                    "city": "MONTPELLIER",
                    "country": "France",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "number": "0610529856",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "emails": [
                {
                    "email": "marianne.dupond@test.com",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "birthday": "1987-11-13",
            "languages": [
                "FR",
                "EN"
            ],
            "socialNetworks": [
                {
                    "socialNetworkId": "marianne.dupond@twitter",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "customFields": [
                {
                    "customFieldKey": "MAIDEN_NAME",
                    "value": "DURAND"
                }
            ]
        },
        "result": "201"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "created": "2022-02-22T00:37:39Z",
            "lastName": "BOND",
            "firstName": "James",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "title": "MR",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "street1": "boulevard des services secrets",
                    "zipCode": "10000",
                    "city": "LONDRES",
                    "country": "Royaume-Uni",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "number": "0600700700",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "emails": [
                {
                    "email": "james.bond@test.com",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "birthday": "1950-07-07",
            "languages": [
                "EN"
            ],
            "socialNetworks": [
                {
                    "socialNetworkId": "james.bond@facebook",
                    "typeKey": "PERSONAL"
                }
            ],
            "customFields": [
                {
                    "customFieldKey": "VIP",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "result": "201"
    }
]
```

The `id` field inside the `data` and the `response` field do not appear, and sometimes the `id` field inside the `data` of the first element appears, sometimes not.

## Affected code

### Bulk insertion(flux of single insertion) code:

```java
    public Flux<SingleResponseBulk> bulkInsertCustomerProfile(Multi<SingleResponseBulk> singleResponses) {
        return Flux.from(singleResponses)
                .doOnEach(signal -> {
                    if (signal.hasValue()) {
                        SingleResponseBulk singleResponseBulk = Objects.requireNonNull(signal.get());
                        insertCustomerProfileWithSingleResponseBulk(singleResponseBulk);
                    }
                });
    }
```

```java
    private void insertCustomerProfileWithSingleResponseBulk(SingleResponseBulk response) {
        try {
            insertCustomerProfile(response.getData()).subscribe();
            response.setId(response.getData().getId());
            response.setResult("201");
        } catch (CouchbaseException e) {
            response.setResult("400");
            response.setError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

### Single insertion code:

```java
    public Mono<CustomerProfile> insertCustomerProfile(CustomerProfile customerProfile) {
        customerProfile.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        return getNextId().flatMap(counterResult -> {
            String id = String.valueOf(counterResult.content());
            customerProfile.setId(id);
            String key = getDocumentKey(id);
            return collection.insert(key, customerProfile)
                    .flatMap(result -> {
                        customerProfile.setCas(result.cas());
                        return Mono.just(customerProfile);
                    })
                    .doOnError(CouchbaseException.class, mapCouchbaseExceptionConsumer(id));
        });

    }
```

### Id generation code:

```java
    private Mono<CounterResult> getNextId() {
        return collection.binary()
                .increment("counter" + COLLECTION_DELIMITER + CUSTOMER_PROFILE_COLLECTION)
                .doOnError(CouchbaseException.class, error -> {
                    String errorMessage = "An exception occurred during id generation.";
                    throw new RepositoryException(errorMessage, error);
                });
    }
```

## Question

So I was wondering if it would be possible to solve the problem. If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Hi @JavaMan. It's a little unclear what the problem is here, it would help if you could simplify it down a bit.  I can say that the reactive chain isn't set up correctly, as you're calling doOnEach rather that flatMap/concatMap.